# How to uppercase every first letter after every point/period in a specific cell in Excel

Tags: excel

Assuming only the first letter after "." needs to be uppercase

=IF(FIND(".",A1)>0,REPLACE(A1,FIND(".",A1)+2,1,UPPER(MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+2,1))),A1)

How can I uppercase every first letter after every point in this specific cell with an Excel formula?

Example:

hello world.hello world. hello World

should be ->

hello world.Hello world. Hello World

Many thanks and cheers!

Comment: I think you will need VBA for this. `PROPER` is close, but not exactly what you need

Comment: An excel-formula would be perfect! Thanks

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood what I meant. I don't think you can do this with a excel formula (at least not to be dynamic enough to capture every instance of a new sentence). This is doable in VBA

Comment: can't I catch every instance of a period in the cell?

Comment: I am using Excel 2010 :(

Comment: It would be a complicated task even if you are using later versions of excel and have access to functions such as **TEXTJOIN**, **FILTERXML**. A manual approach would be using text to columns function to split your sentence by full-stop `.`, then use **LEFT+UPPER+RIGHT** functions to convert the first letter of each sub-sentence to upper case, and then combine each sub-sentence. I guess `vba` may be a better approach in your case so you may want to add `#vba` to your tags and good luck.

Comment: Just curious are you using Excel 2010 Professional Plus version and have access to **#powerquery**? Which can also tackle this problem.

Comment: Not all of the characters you wish to capitalize are following a dot.  In the second instance, the character you wish to capitalize is following a `space`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with udearboy that `PROPER` is the way to go. `PROPER` seems to capitalize the first letter after each period AND the first letter in the string. So, concatenate the first part of the string (up to the first period) with the proper case of the rest of the string:

`=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1))&PROPER(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1))),A1)`

I added the `IFERROR` in case the string has no periods.

Comment: Short, code-only answers are often frowned upon on Stack Overflow. In order to avoid being removed as 'low quality', please add some explanatory text.

Comment: @Adrian Noted. Thanks for the correction. I'll try to avoid answering when I'm mobile until I can type up a more detailed explanation.